# How do I uninstall the uuid_ossp module in postgresql 9.0.4?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I used the following command to install the postgres UUID_OSSP module in version 9.0.4 :

```
$psql -d <database> -U <user> -f <path to>/uuid-ossp.sql
```

How do I uninstall this? I am exporting this database and I don't want this to show up in the DB export script. I'm no longer using the module. I found a lot of answers related to *installation* of this module but not *uninstallation*.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a `uninstall_uuid-ossp.sql` script in the same directory where `uuid-ossp.sql` is located.